# Deploy to Heroku Error

Tags: deployment, heroku, sqlite, rubygems, installation

I am failing to deploy my first app to Heroku. An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `**gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6**'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     *Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app*

After the I modified the Gemfile and installed sqlite3 1.3.6 by using the command:

user$ gem install sqlite3 1.3.6

I got:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.6
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem ',' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '~>1.3.6' (>= 0) in any repository
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-1.3.6.

Just a note, I have deleted the Gemfile.lock but haven't committed the changes. Please help me install the necessary gems to deploy to Heroku

Comment: Feel free to use sqlite3 while developing, but heroku uses PostgreSQL as default database, so you should add `gem 'pg'` into Gemgile and move your `gem 'sqlite3'` under block `group :development`. After you changed Gemfile, execute command `bundle`, and commit updated versions of Gemfile and Gemfile.lock into the repository.

Comment: I did: **group :production**  *do* gem 'pg' gem 'thin' *end*    **group :development** *do* gem 'sqlite3' *end*. Committed the changes in **COMMITMSG** file user$ commit -m "ready to deploy to heroku" and pushed the bundle command in the terminal, but now I getting `Invalid RUBY_VERSION specified: Gemfile-syntax-error:-gem-'sqlite3'-,-:group-=>-[:-development,-:test]-^-/tmp/build_2zorjkjw7z7gk/Gemfile:8:-syntax-error,-unexpected-']',-expecting-tCOLON2-or-'['-or-'.'` Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined). Help!

Comment: Please show your complete Gemfile.